PCP is undecidable, but seems also NP
I've seen the proof that the Post Correspondence Problem is undecidable -- let's call this the problem of taking a finite collection of tiles with top and bottom labeled by any two strings, and finding a sequence of tiles which produce the same total string on the top and bottom rows.
However, it seems that it should also be NP because any certificate is checkable in polynomial time.  By analogy, we confirm that the primality of an integer is NP because we can check a certificate (a pair of integers which claim to multiply to the given integer) in polynomial time.
Yet, I believe that NP also implies decidable -- because it is provably equivalent to "can be decided by a nondeterministic Turing machine".
Can anyone resolve this seeming contradiction?

The issue is: how do you know whether or not the candidate solution is polynomial in the size of the input? Certainly in the size of the candidate you can just concatenate the top and bottom strings in polynomial time, but that's not how we measure run time.
